# How to make multiple QED squares side by side on the right

Tags: symbols, proof-package

I have a long proof that features two lemmas; at their end, I want to make three QED signs side by side on the right side of the page. If I use `\endproof\endproof`, the squares are vertically placed and take a lot of the page, if I use `\qed\qed\qed` I get squares [image: here] and if I use `\qedhere\quedhere`, only one `\qedhere` renders.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you are using `amsthm`, the `\qedsymbol` is defined as either `\textbox` or `\openbox`.  What you need to do is locally redefine `\qedsymbol` to include three of the desired shapes: `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\openbox\openbox\openbox}`

Comment: You should *never* use `\endproof` to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to keep it simple, here is a macro `\qeds[<number]` that will place `<number>` `\qedsymbol`s at the end of the proof. Default is 2. Does not work if `<number>`=1.

[image]

I put a thin space `\,` between the symbols in the macro but you can change that however you like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,pgffor}

\newcommand{\qeds}[1][2]{\qedhere\foreach\n in{2,...,#1}{\,\qedsymbol}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Here is a proof!
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Here is a proof!\qeds
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Here is a proof!\qeds[3]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Never use `\proof` and `\endproof` in the document, but `\begin{proof}` and `\end{proof}`. You're looking for trouble, otherwise.

Maybe something like the following?

Here I do use `\proof` and `\endproof`, but hidden in the definition of `proofnoqed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\NewCommandCopy{\QEDSYM}{\qedsymbol}
\newenvironment{proofnoqed}[1][\proofname]
 {\proof[#1]\renewcommand{\qed}{}}
 {\endproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Pigs can't fly.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\QEDSYM\,\QEDSYM\,\QEDSYM}
We will divide the proof in two lemmas.

\begin{lemma}\label{pigs-4l}
Pigs are four-legged.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proofnoqed}[Proof of lemma~\ref{pigs-4l}]
This should be obvious as soon as you look at a pig.
\end{proofnoqed}

\begin{lemma}\label{4l-nofly}
No four-legged animal can fly.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proofnoqed}[Proof of lemma~\ref{4l-nofly}]
By contradiction. Suppose a four-legged animal can fly. This would
imply that the sky is pink, which it isn't.
\end{proofnoqed}

The two lemmas finish the proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can we automate the procedure? Yes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcounter{noqed}
\NewCommandCopy{\QEDSYM}{\qedsymbol}
\newenvironment{proofnoqed}[1][\proofname]
 {\stepcounter{noqed}\proof[#1]\renewcommand{\qed}{}}
 {\endproof}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{noqed}{0}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { \value{noqed} } { \QEDSYM\, } \QEDSYM
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Pigs can't fly.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We will divide the proof in two lemmas.

\begin{lemma}\label{pigs-4l}
Pigs are four-legged.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proofnoqed}[Proof of lemma~\ref{pigs-4l}]
This should be obvious as soon as you look at a pig.
\end{proofnoqed}

\begin{lemma}\label{4l-nofly}
No four-legged animal can fly.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proofnoqed}[Proof of lemma~\ref{4l-nofly}]
By contradiction. Suppose a four-legged animal can fly. This would
imply that the sky is pink, which it isn't.
\end{proofnoqed}

The two lemmas finish the proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Some birds can fly.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Look in the sky.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]